# listener function on page refresh

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Can add a listener to whenever a page is refreshed or clicked?

When the page is refreshed it needs to call this function:

```
TableTT.hide()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML page reloads can be reacted to by placing the appropriate code in an `window.onload` handler, some more info: http://roberthahn.ca/articles/2007/02/02/how-to-use-window-onload-the-right-way/

in general javascript you could do

```
window.onload = function () {
    TableTT.hide();
}
```

in [ext-js](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/) you can simply add the function to your [listeners](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-listeners)

```
var eg = Ext.create('widget.window', { width: 600, height: 800, ... });
eg.on('load', function(){
              TableTT.hide();
             } );
eg.load();
```